# pandas get row index list by condition in apply funciton

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2', '3'],
                   ['4.5', '5', '6'],
                   ['7.5', '8', '9'],
                   ['10', '11', '12']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(int)

# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.5'
```

i trying get row index list what raise error in series. in the case, i wanna get [0, 1].
it is simple if i use for loop, but i wanna use just apply or numpy vectorization. can i get some clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with where after we get the round of the value

```
out = df.where(df.astype(float).ne(df.astype(float).round())).stack()
Out[368]: 
1  col1    4.5
2  col1    7.5
dtype: object
```

> Index level 0 is your row index , and level 1 is the column

Comment: thanks a lot! i solve this problem with your answer :)

Comment: @PSW yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return True

f = np.vectorize(f)
np.where(f(df))
#(array([1, 2]), array([0, 0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to define a function that captures the exception and apply it to the dataframe with a lambda, creating a new column that shows the exceptions.

```
def raises_error(row):
    try:
        for i in range(3):
            int(row[i])
        return "NO"
    except(ValueError):
        return "YES"


df['Error'] = df.apply(lambda row: raises_error(row), axis = 1)
print(df)

#.   col1 col2 col3 Error
#. 0    1    2    3    NO
#. 1  4.5    5    6   YES
#. 2  7.5    8    9   YES
#. 3   10   11   12    NO
```